# SELECT statement returns no results on iOS 8.2 (SQL 3.8.4)

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios8.2

The SELECT statement below worked perfectly fine on iOS 8.1 and prior versions. Now on my updated device with iOS 8.2 it simply returns no results without any error. I figured out that iOS 8.2 updated the SQLite version from 3.7.13 to 3.8.4. This seems to be the issue because I haven't changed anything else.

```
SELECT * FROM allLanguages WHERE allLanguages MATCH '*searchString*' (doesn't work --> no results)
```

As I played around a little it seems that the issue is the 'prefixed' wildcard *. Dropping this returns results.

```
SELECT * FROM allLanguages WHERE allLanguages MATCH 'searchString*' (works)

SELECT * FROM allLanguages WHERE allLanguages MATCH '*searchString' (doesn't work --> no results)

SELECT * FROM allLanguages WHERE allLanguages MATCH '*searchString*' (doesn't work --> no results)
```

Does anyone know whats the issue here? And can the SELECT statement may be substituted by a different one which works under SQL 3.8.4?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research putting double quotes around the **'"*searchString*"'** did the trick for me. Can't explain why but it works ;)

```
SELECT * FROM allLanguages WHERE allLanguages MATCH '"*searchString*"'
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but your solution seems to be not perfect: it returns only the matching texts languages who STARTS with the 'searchString'. Is it right?

Comment: Surrounding the searchString with a leading * and a trailing * also returns results where the searchString occurs at an arbitrary position, not only at the beginning. That's what I experiencing. Have you tried it with the leading * AND the trailing *?

Comment: FYI: if you use this statement in the context of a NSString in Objective C you have to escape the double quotes with a \. E.g. NSString *query = @"SELECT * FROM allLanguages WHERE allLanguages MATCH '\"*searchString*\"'"; This might help.

Comment: Of course, that's exactly what I use, with the double quotes escaped, but it returns only the entries who starts with my research text... Before the iOS update, it works correctly and returned all occurences, whenever the search text was at the beginning or at the end... That's avery strainge comportment.

Comment: I am sorry having confused you. You were right. It only matches words starting with the "searchString". What I related to was matching words in the middle of a "sentence". e.g. if you search for "fun" it will match "this is a funtastic bar". After some research it looks like the leading asteriks wont work on fts working with MATCH.

Comment: I am building a solution for my app around this https://github.com/haifengkao/SqliteSubstringSearch right now. With the use of a custom tokenizer this will also allows you to match substrings in words at an arbitrary position. Might help you as well.